# What is the PDF of the distances between points for an uniformly selected set of points in the unit square?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Specifically, if I have a random variable $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed according to $D = \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$. How do I compute the PDF of $Z = \left|(X,Y) - (X,Y)\right|$?

I tried the following steps:

1. Calculate the PDF of $Z_1 = X-X$
2. Calculate the PDF of $Z_2 = (Z_1)^2$
3. Calculate the PDF of $Z_3 = Z_2 + Z_2$
4. Calculate the PDF of $Z_4 = \sqrt{Z_3}$

And I believe my calculations are correct up to step 2., but after that the PDFs stop matching with my simulations. I also asked the same question on Quora, but the answer (https://www.quora.com/Given-a-set-of-uniformly-selected-2D-points-in-the-unit-square-what-is-the-PDF-of-the-distances-between-them-1) also does not match with my simulations.

For your consideration, here is my simulation: [Distances histogram for 1000 uniformly selected points in the unit square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvXl1.png).

Comment: Just for notation, in the definition of $Z$, you meant $Z = \left|(X,Y) - (X',Y')\right|$ where $(X,Y),(X',Y')$ are iid with uniform law on $D$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: what other information on $X$ and $Y$ ?

Comment: Both are uniformly distributed